# replace part of text after split in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following html structure:

```
<a href="example.com/post_10.html" id="titlelink">Name - post title 2017</a>
```

I want to remove 2017 + Name and keep post title

```
$.each($('a#itlelink'), function(i){
    var content = $(this).text();
    content = content.split('-')[1];
    $(this).text(content);
});
```

I tried many ways and did not work!!

any idea?

Comment: Can you give examples of possible titles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the string is always with `2017`, you can use a simple `replace`:

```
content = content.split('-')[1].replace(' 2017', '');
```

If the `2017` changes according to current date's year, use `replace` with `getYear()` like this:

```
var date = new Date();
content = content.split('-')[1].replace(date.getYear(), '');
```

Here's a working snippet:

```js
$.each($('a'), function(i){
    var content = $(this).text();
    content = content.split('-')[1].replace(' 2017','');
    console.log(content);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="example.com/post_10.html" id="titlelink">Name - post title 2017</a>
```

Comment: the string is always with 2017, but i tried this way before, but it's not working

Comment: @AliRamadhan What's not working exactly? Please elaborate.